# Why does a Gaussian process have a gradient whose determinant is Gaussian?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random, random-functions

I'm trying to understand something in Adler and Taylor's book, *Random Fields and Geometry*.

Let $T \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a compact parameter set (for simplicity, suppose it is a closed hypercube) and let $f : T \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be a random field that is a.s. in $C^1(T)$.

We define by $\nabla f$ the $N\times N$ matrix of first-order partial derivatives $$\nabla f(t) = \left(\frac {\partial f_i}{\partial t_j}(t)\right)_{i,j}$$

In **Theorem 11.2.1** (page 267), several assumptions are made, including the following "assumption (d)":

> **(d)** The conditional densities $p_t(z|f(t)=x)$ of $\det \nabla f(t)$ given $f(t)=x$, are continuous for $z$ and $x$ in neighborhoods of $0$ and $u$, respectively, uniformly in $t \in T$.

On the beginning of the next page (page 268), the following paragraph appears:

> [When the random field $f$ is Gaussian,] the marginal and conditional densities appearing in the conditions of Theorem 11.2.1 are also Gaussian, and so their boundedness and continuity are immediate, as long as all the associated covariance matrices are nondegenerate, which is what we'll need to assume in this case.

**I don't understand why this is true.** (Specifically, I'm interested only in condition (d) which I quoted.)

Regardless of the above, ultimately, I want to prove the following: For any $t$ and small enough $A$, we have $\mathbb P\left\{|\det \nabla f(t)| \le A\right\} \le MA$ for some constant $M$. ($f$ is Gaussian, and maybe satisfies certain nondegeneracy conditions.) It doesn't seem like $\det \nabla f(t)$ should be Gaussian, since it is a sum of *products* of Gaussians... But I don't need it to be Gaussian, just the above bound.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think it is relatively easy to prove that all partial derivatives are Gaussian (if you use the definition of the derivative as a limit, and then use convergence of normal variables). Then, with some extra assumptions, you can prove gradient vector with multivariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: This I know how to do. But - what about the determinant of the gradient? The gradient is a multinormal $N\times N$ matrix where distinct entries might not be independent, and the determinant is some degree-$N$ polynomial in these entries...

Comment: Right, it looks more like the determinant should have chi-square distribution or something more exotic. Apparently, the authors only wanted to say that the distributions of f and its gradient are gaussian.

I believe the inequality you want to prove can be deduced from the condition (g) about the modulus of continuity

Comment: That's very interesting. Could you please expand on how it can be deduced? It seems strange to me that (g) would suffice, because in the simple but extreme case where $f=0$ always, (g) seems to be satisfied, but obviously not the inequality I want. That's why I think maybe it's necessary to work with the densities, because just assuming they exist kills such counterexamples.